# ATmega328P ADC 4-digit 7-seg display

Tags: adc, potentiometer, 7segmentdisplay, atmega328p

I've been trying to program an ADC with my ATmega328P, coding it in C++, it should show a 0 to 1023 value number, but it keeps showing random numbers when I move the potentiometer: 0001, 0039, 0014, 0053, 0027, 0001, 0039, 0013, 0052, 0026, 0063.

Can someone help me, I'm still a beginner.

[image]

```c
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// Definir los valores de los segmentos para mostrar dígitos en el display de 7 segmentos
int seg7_1[10] = {0x3F, 0x06, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0x07, 0x7F, 0x67};

// Inicializar el ADC
void ADC_init()
{
    ADMUX = (1 << REFS0); // AVCC con un condensador externo en el pin AREF
    ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0); // Habilitar el ADC, prescaler de 8
}

// Leer el valor del ADC
uint16_t read_ADC(uint8_t channel)
{
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF0) | (channel & 0x0F); // Seleccionar el canal ADC con una máscara de seguridad
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // Iniciar la conversión
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)); // Esperar a que la conversión se complete
    return ADC;
}

// Suavizar el valor del ADC
uint16_t smooth_ADC(uint8_t channel)
{
    static uint16_t readings[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint32_t sum = 0;

    // Desplazar las lecturas
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        readings[i] = readings[i + 1];
        sum += readings[i];
    }

    // Tomar una nueva lectura
    readings[3] = read_ADC(channel);
    sum += readings[3];

    // Calcular el promedio
    return sum / 4;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Configurar los pines de salida
    DDRB = 0xFF; // 1111 1111
    DDRD = 0xF0; // 1111 0000
    DDRC &= ~(1 << PC0); // Configurar PC0 como entrada
    PORTC |= (1 << PC0); // Habilitar pull-up en PC0

    // Inicializar el ADC
    ADC_init();

    while (1)
    {
        // Obtener el valor suavizado del ADC desde PC0
        uint16_t adc_value = smooth_ADC(0);
        
        // Escalar el valor del ADC al rango de 0 a 1023
        adc_value = adc_value * 1024 / 1023;

        // Separar el valor en dígitos individuales
        int i, j, k, z;
        i = adc_value % 10;
        j = (adc_value / 10) % 10;
        k = (adc_value / 100) % 10;
        z = (adc_value / 1000) % 10;

        // Mostrar los dígitos en el display de 7 segmentos
        PORTD |= 1 << PORTD4;
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5) & ~(1 << PORTD6) & ~(1 << PORTD7); // 0100
        PORTB = seg7_1[z];
        _delay_ms(1);

        PORTD |= 1 << PORTD5;
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6) & ~(1 << PORTD7) & ~(1 << PORTD4); // 0010
        PORTB = seg7_1[k];
        _delay_ms(1);

        PORTD |= 1 << PORTD6;
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD7) & ~(1 << PORTD4) & ~(1 << PORTD5); // 0001
        PORTB = seg7_1[j];
        _delay_ms(1);

        PORTD |= 1 << PORTD7;
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD4) & ~(1 << PORTD5) & ~(1 << PORTD6); // 1000
        PORTB = seg7_1[i];
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you multiply a 16-bit variable adc_value with 1024 and divide by 1023 as it makes no sense? Just remove it.

The variable already is up to 1023 and multiplying it with 1024 will not fit into a 16-bit integer. It will be truncated to 0xFC00, which divided by 1023 is 63 what you see on the LED display.

So code does exactly what it is told to do actually. You just expect it to do something else.

Even if it did not overflow, it would not show your expected 0..1023 range because your code just scaled it to 0..1024.